# File Viewing code in XML (Samsung Galaxy Y)

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm developing an android app to transfer files to a computer over a local area network.
I have finished the layout in XML, but one of my options is to open the files within the phone.

Does anyone know the code to view the files within my phone? or is there another way around it like using the default files application already installed on my phone?

I essentially need to be able to view the files so that the user can select which files need to be sent.

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Thanks a lot.